# ~/.profile doesn't run after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, command-line, bash, login, zsh

After upgrading Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10, `~/.profile` file has suddenly stopped running on login.
Therefore, the script below, which is located in `~/.profile` isn't run

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

How to make `~/.profile` run again on startup? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it sourced if you select a gnome session (in place of the default - I think -Wayland session)?

Comment: @steeldriver good question. Just checked: when I choose "Ubuntu" (default) it **doesn't** work, but when I choose "Ubuntu on Xorg" or "Unity" it **does** work.

Comment: Yeah - I think that's just a "feature" of the Wayland session (it doesn't invoke a login shell) - not sure if there's a way to change that

Comment: @steeldriver seems awkward to me, many thanks anyway.

Comment: Some suggestions here: [GNOME, Wayland, and environment variables](https://lwn.net/Articles/709769/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that Ubuntu 17.10 uses Wayland as the default desktop session - which unlike traditional X-Windows desktops, does not invoke a user's login shell (or in fact any shell).

The recommended workaround from [Initiatives/Wayland/Session Start GNOME Wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/SessionStart) is given as follows:

> The simplest way to set environment variables for a single user under
>   systemd (version 233 or later), is to create a `.conf` file in
>   `~/.config/environment.d`, containing lines of the form `NAME=VAL`. See
>   the environment.d documentation for more details.
>
> GDM also supports the `/usr/share/gdm/env.d/` drop-in directory. Files
>   dropped in there also contain lines of the form `NAME=VAL`. These affect
>   all users of the system.

For additional discussion see the article [GNOME, Wayland, and environment variables](https://lwn.net/Articles/709769/).