# Alias in terminal no longer works in 17.10

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I must have done something to my environment in Ubuntu 17.10 as alias in the  terminal no longer works. Probably/Maybe after a `apt-get autoremove` (I guess).

Open a terminal and running `echo $shell` shows nothing but an empty row. I run `ps -p $$` and it shows that I'm in bash.

.bash_profile and alias are being recognized if I run `source .bash_profile`.

What could have happened and what can I do to get alias working again without needing to run `source`?

Comment: I suspect the cause is the same as here [~/.profile doesn't run after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000496/profile-doesnt-run-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-17-10) - probably the easiest solution is to move the alias definitions to `~/.bashrc`, which is sourced for *non*-login shells (such as those run in the desktop terminal emulator). BTW `echo $shell` is not the same as `echo $SHELL`

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you. The strange thing is that it worked before.

Comment: GNOME Terminal doesn't run login shells by default. You have to set it do so. Probably you did at one time and unset it some other time.

Comment: @muru I think steeldriver pinned down the issue here (Wayland doesn't run a login shell). Voted to reopen.

Comment: @WJAndrea which would be irrelevant for aliases. Aliases don't inherit from the environment, so even if Wayland ran a login shell and read `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, it wouldn't create aliases in bash run in GNOME Terminal.

Comment: @muru Oh, you're right, sorry.

Comment: @muru I appreciate the work you do here but the system of marking duplicates is not always fair. Take my question as an example. Unless you're an expert you don't know it's the same problem, though after a while I understood it. But perhaps this is a place for professionals. I says this as I got a warning that I might not be able to ask again.

Comment: @PalBergstrom have an upvote, that should hold off the block for now. Note that deleting questions makes it look worse for the autoblock, so don't delete a post if it was marked as a dupe.